# How can I upload object(.csv,.sav) to azure blob without save at local?

Tags: dataframe, csv, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to upload `.csv` and `.sav` file to azure storage without save at local. All objects are present in memory itself.

I tried with `BlobServiceClient`, `ContainerClient` class but not found any methods.
Same things I'm able to do in GCP using:

```
bucket.blob(fileName).upload_from_string(df.to_csv(index=False), 'text/csv')
```

Is there any way to do same in Azure?

Comment: So basically, your server will generate .csv content and you want to upload it to storage blob directly by python?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Right now all things is in my local itself. But on later stage it will move to some remote server and from there I want to upload directly. so I don't want any dependency on local.

Comment: Yes, @StanleyGong. Thank you

Comment: Glad to know that my solution is helpful. Please click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in to accept it as an answer, so that it will help others and close this query : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your code and your requirement, you want to upload .csv file content in a string directly, I write a simple demo for you, just try code below:

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobClient

storage_connection_string=''
container_name = 'files'
dest_file_name = 'test.csv'

blob_client = BlobClient.from_connection_string(storage_connection_string,container_name,dest_file_name)

csv_content = "name,id,department,\nstan,001,dev,\ntom,002,dev,"

blob_client.upload_blob(csv_content)
```

Result:

[image]

download and open it as .csv:

[image]